# How can I run a Maven webapp in Eclipse when I need resource filtering for properties files?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, tomcat, maven, m2e

I need to get some updates on this issue, I found [this thread back in 2009 here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669639/how-can-i-run-a-maven-webapp-in-eclipse-when-i-use-profiles-to-populate-properti), but the answer was to use maven 2, I'm not sure if Q4E works with maven 3 or not. I need to have some properties files filtered during the mvn package phase for the resulting war to be functional, the resource filtering is working fine with CLI mvn install. But when I do "Run on server/debug on server", the filtering is not working any more.
The aforementioned thread author ended up using q4e, claiming q4e gets the resource filtering right. I have q4e installed as well along with m2e, but still doesn't work, so I don't know if q4e is not working with maven 3, or I'm doing something wrong.
Thanks,

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated to the latest m2e-wtp plugin 0.15 (resource filtering bug fix since 0.12), it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this matches your problem, but I wanted to populate my web.xml file with properties from the pom during build and I put a groovy script in the pom to do it. It worked a treat and might work for you too. It definately works in both eclipse and on the command line. Here is my pom fragment:

```
  <plugin>
<!-- Groovy script to set the description and version in the web.xml display name -->
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>groovy-magic</id>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>execute</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <source>
            def file = new File("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml");
            def fileText = file.text;
            def match = "&lt;display-name>[^&lt;]*&lt;/display-name>";
            def replace = "&lt;display-name>"+project.description+" "+project.version+"&lt;/display-name>";
            fileText = fileText.replaceAll(match, replace);
            file.write(fileText);
            println "Updated web.xml"
          </source>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: The xml processing as text rather than dom is a complete hack, I agree.

Comment: Thanks for accepting this, although I'm a little surprised - I read up on the resource filtering and its a much higher level and potentially interesting thing than my little hack, which does what I need but clearly not what you need.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out. I must have approved the wrong answer,sorry. Actually, my answer using m2e-wtp plugin 0.15 (>0.12) should be way to go